# Angular mock Spec

Tags: angular, mocking, specifications, ng-mocks

I am using ng-mocks this way -

```
import { MockDirective, MockComponent, ngMocks } from 'ng-mocks';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ 
                      MockComponent(ComponentName),

      ],

      schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]

    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I am seeing the below error -

```
Failed: ng-mocks is not in JIT mode and cannot resolve declarations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been fixed recently. In your case, it means that `ComponentName` has been imported wrongly, or has a wrong type.

`MockComponent` accepts classes. Therefore, it should be used like:

```js
import { MockDirective, MockComponent, ngMocks } from 'ng-mocks';

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ 
      MockComponent(ComponentClass), // <- its class instead of its name.
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after upgrading my project from angular @12.2.16 to @13.2.4. However I was getting the exact same error:

`MyComponent declaration has been passed into ng-mocks without Angular decorators. Therefore, it cannot be properly handled. Highly likely, jest.mock() has been used on its file, or ng-mocks is not in JIT mode`

My project versions:

- ng-mocks: 12.5.1
- @angular/core: 13.2.4

After trying a lot of possible solutions a could solve my problem just reinstalling ng-mocks with the latest version and everything  got fixed up and all tests were passing successfully.

Update ng-mocks to the latest version with:

```
$ npm uninstall ng-mocks
$ npm install ng-mocks@latest --save-dev
```

Good lucky, hope this help someone else.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and the ng-mocks dependency that I had was 12.5.x and after the upgrade to 13.x.x it's fixed. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the accepted answer: I also ran into the `"...without Angular Decorators..."` error.

In my case the embedded component was *in its own module*. I therefore had to import the module (or use `MockModule` instead of `MockComponent`) in the Testbed and everything worked smooth after that.